# Geopandas some shapes not outlined -- Want to update background?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

I am using Geopandas to map counts on a US Map. I want to change the background of the plot/figure to black, but I cannot locate a setting in Geopandas.

My guess is I need to use matplotlib. I sift through this doc but I don't see anything related to background. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
import geopandas as gpd

us_map = gpd.read_file('tl_2020_us_state.shp')

names = ['Alaska', 'Hawaii', 'United States Virgin Islands', 'Commonwealth of the Northern Mariana Islands', 'Guam', 'American Samoa', 'Puerto Rico']

updated_us_map = us_map.loc[~(us_map)['NAME'].isin(names)]

state_occurrences = us_only_places_df['State'].value_counts().reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'NAME','State':'count'})

merge_map = updated_us_map.merge(state_occurrences, on='NAME')
merge_map.plot(column='count', cmap='Oranges', legend=True, legend_kwds={'label': "Number of Places", 'orientation': "vertical", 'shrink':0.4}, figsize=(15,20), edgecolor='black', set_facecolor = '#F0F0F0')
plt.title('Count of Places Saved for each US States')
```

[image]

UPDATING CODE PER SUGGESTION:

```
import geopandas as gpd

us_map = gpd.read_file('tl_2020_us_state.shp')
names = ['Alaska', 'Hawaii', 'United States Virgin Islands', 'Commonwealth of the Northern Mariana Islands', 'Guam', 'American Samoa', 'Puerto Rico']
updated_us_map = us_map.loc[~(us_map)['NAME'].isin(names)]
state_occurrences = us_only_places_df['State'].value_counts().reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'NAME','State':'count'})
merge_map = updated_us_map.merge(state_occurrences, on='NAME')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2,2))
merge_map.plot(column='count', cmap='Oranges', legend=True, legend_kwds={'label': "Number of Places", 'orientation': "vertical", 'shrink':0.4}, figsize=(5,5), edgecolor='black')
plt.title('Count of Places Saved for each US States')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, you could use matplotlib with its module pyplot (`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`) and the `subplots` func.

You can try something like this:

```
us_map = gpd.read_file('tl_2020_us_state.shp')

names = ['Alaska', 'Hawaii', 'United States Virgin Islands', 'Commonwealth of the Northern Mariana Islands', 'Guam', 'American Samoa', 'Puerto Rico']

updated_us_map = us_map.loc[~(us_map)['NAME'].isin(names)]

merge_map = updated_us_map.merge(state_occurrences, on='NAME')

state_occurrences = us_only_places_df['State'].value_counts().reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'NAME','State':'count'})

updated_us_map = us_map.loc[~(us_map)['NAME'].isin(names)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,16))
us_map.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.4)
merge_map.plot(column='count', cmap='Oranges', legend=True, legend_kwds={'label': "Number of Places", 'orientation': "vertical", 'shrink':0.4}, figsize=(15,20), edgecolor='black', set_facecolor = '#F0F0F0')
```

Let me know if this works, you can change the transparency with the input argument in `alpha=0.4`

Comment: I removed the set_facecolor because I received the following error: AttributeError: PatchCollection.set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'set_facecolor'. I ran the updated code (updated above) and i returned two charts, but no background color changes. The first chart is empty with x and y axis, the second is the original choropleth

Comment: Just curious, I am not familiar with this notation fig, ax... How did you know to do that? I feel like I am missing something in the documentation. Likely a severe gap in my knowledge -- I don't really know Python very well.